# jQuery to pass to MVC asp.net c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I changed some things around for an item that was requested.  This required me to add a parameter to one of the controller ActionResults.

```
public ActionResult RejectDocument(int id = 0, string rejectReason)
        {
            IPACS_Version ipacs_version = db.IPACS_Version.Find(id);

            ipacs_version.dateDeleted = System.DateTime.Now;
            ipacs_version.deletedBy = User.Identity.Name.Split("\\".ToCharArray())[1];

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Approve");
        }
```

Also this link needs to be activated from jQuery after some jQuery items finish.  How do I pass this link off now?

should it be `href= Document/RejectDocument?id=222&rejectReason=this is my reject reason`

could I then do `window.location = href;` and it would call the controller and pass in the correct information?

Comment: Did you try it?  Is it not working for you in some way?

Comment: Could post your javascript code?

Comment: maybe you should think about using the post request instead of get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Url` helper to create the right url using the table routes rules. For sample:

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("RejectDocument", "YourController", new { id = 222, rejectReason = "this is my reject reason" })';
```

Comment: This worked for me although I didn't use @Url.Action, I just plugged in the href.  Thank you! :)